# Dropbox API - Call to undefined function readline()

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I have the following code

```
<?php
// Include DropBox API
require_once "dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php";
use \Dropbox as dbx;
// Settings for DropBox
$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("config.json");
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "PHP-Example/1.0");

$authCode = \trim(\readline("A-WALID-KEY-HERE"));

list($accessToken, $dropboxUserId) = $webAuth->finish($authCode);
print "Access Token: " . $accessToken . "\n";

?>
```

Bud i get this error when i run the code.
Call to undefined function readline()

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php5-readline` might fix the issue, if you're on a Unix-based distro. See [this post on AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/183038/133170) for more details.

Comment: It's on a domain hosted by One.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds from your comment like you're trying to run this as a web app. If so, you're going to run into trouble. This looks like the command-line app example code, which is why it uses `readline` (which reads input from the command-line).

You might want to start from the `web-file-browser` example that ships with the SDK. This is meant to be run as a web app and should show you to how to do (among other things) authentication in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the same code. You have forgotten to add this:

```
    $authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();
```

just right after this line:

```
    $webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "PHP-Example/1.0");
```

What you have to do is to use the created link stored in the variable $authorizeUrl to get the authorization code.
 After doing this you need to use the authorization code to generate a token. For this comment the part of your code like that:

```
  <?php
  // Include DropBox API
  require_once "dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php";
  use \Dropbox as dbx;
  // Settings for DropBox
  //$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("config.json");
  //$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "PHP-Example/1.0");
  //**$authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();**

  $authCode = \trim(\readline("**A-WALID-KEY-HERE**"));

  list($accessToken, $dropboxUserId) = $webAuth->finish($authCode);
  print "Access Token: " . $accessToken . "\n";

  ?>
```

Once you get the token save it somewhere safe and comment also the rest of the lines. Then you can access dropbox with no problem. For example:

```
 $dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");
 $accountInfo = $dbxClient->getAccountInfo();
```